# How to preserve trailing spaces in a string when printing it onto a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

When I am trying to print out strings with a trailing space, the trailing spaces are automatically truncated by excel. I want to preserve them.

Sample:

```
Sub stringspace()

stringg = "23 "
MsgBox Len(stringg) 'here it is 3
Cells(1, 1) = stringg
MsgBox Len(Cells(1, 1)) 'here it is 2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Text format to prevent autoconversion:

```vb
Sub stringspace()

    stringg = "23 "
    MsgBox Len(stringg) 'here it is 3
    Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
    Cells(1, 1) = stringg
    MsgBox Len(Cells(1, 1)) 'here it is 3

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub StringSpace_Modified()

    Cells(2, 1) = "'23 "  ' Use a single quote at the beginning
    Debug.Print Len(Cells(2, 1)) ' Displays 3 in immediate window

End Sub
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer (by adding the '), but the method to check is not valid.  A cell might still trim the spaces, but the len function on the cell still will show the entire string length.  For example `Cells(1,1) = "23 ": Cells(1,2) = "123": If Len(Cells(1,1)) = Len(Cells(1,2))` would evaluate to true.  [If the comment doesn't properly show it "23 " does indeed have a space in it]